# Past day vs. Passed day

Tags: grammar, phrasing

I am writing an account of something, and I'm not sure whether I should say "passed day", as in "Day that has passed" or "past day", as in "Day in the past".

> In the evenings we would get together to discuss the passed day, what challenges we faced and plan for the next day.

Note: I noticed a few similar questions but they did not answer this question.

Comment: If you use *passed* you would be better off putting the time period before it: *day passed* instead of *passed day*. It would be short for *day just passed*, with its obvious meaning. (Cf. month passed, year passed, etc.) If you use *past*, use it before the time period. In point of fact you could use either, depending on what you wish to emphasize.

Comment: Presumably I'd have to re-structure the sentence to suit that?
"discuss the day passed" doesn't seem right to me

Comment: Then use *past day*.

Comment: In the above sentence it should be "past day".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Passed* is the past participle of the verb *to pass*. 
*To pass* means to proceed, move forward, depart or to cause one of these actions. This can refer to movement forwards in time, in space, or in life (such as to pass a car, which then becomes the passed car).

Passed is almost always a verb; there are a few exceptions; the only other one I can think of at the moment, though, is a sports reference: The passed ball went over the intended receiver's head.

***Past day*** is correct.